# Cross domain XMLHttpRequest in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

My code is working fine till i migrate it to another server with firewall. After since, some part of my code is not working. Its seem to be the xmlhttp POST problem. Can someone point me to the right direction and how to determine if the firewall is the problem. My client insisted to me to use classic asp, so i cannot upgrade to .net.

```
Dim objHttp
SUBMIT_URL = "http://www.abc.com/confirm.asp"

Call Process()

 Public Sub Process()

  set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

  'set the timeout values in milliseconds
  lResolve = 1 * 1000
  lConnect = 1 * 1000
  lSend  = 2 * 1000
  lReceive = 2 * 1000

  objHttp.open "POST", SUBMIT_URL, false
  objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  objHttp.Send str
  if err.number <> 0 then
   Response.Write "Error : " & err.Description
   err.Clear 
  end if

 End Sub
```

Comment: Is there some sort of proxy that's required to get http access from behind the firewall?

Comment: You should not use Microsoft.XMLHTTP on server side, use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP instead.

Also you may need to append "; charset=UTF-8" after the content-type.

Comment: as @thomask said, use ServerXMLHTTP. you may also have to configure  it to use a proxy. `proxycfg -u` will allow you to do this

Answer (score 1):

It's working almost fine for me.  Seems that there's a redirection on the landing page you're calling that cannot be handled.  Doesn't seems to be a firewall problem (maybe a proxy application like Charles or Fiddler can help you to see if there are communication problems due to your firewall, but I don't think so).

So try to point to the final destination page:

**SUBMIT_URL = "http://abc.go.com/confirm.asp"**

I don't really see the point on the timeouts variables unless you cut out come of the code before posting here.